# 0 error interpolation for discrete finite value points

Tags: numerical-analysis, numerical-algorithms

I am working on an algorithm that requires me to interpolate a couple trillion positive discrete points with f(x) having low finite value (for example 0 - 5). It there a specialized algorithm specific for this reduced problem that can provide 0 error interpolation?
Could you maybe point me to a few papers?

EDIT: I noticed that i can make the trillions of points become less, but then the max value of f(x) rises exponentially (if i cut them by half, the max value gets squared). If i can get for example 4 points and interpolate with a 3rd degree function, is it guaranteed to pass through all points?

Comment: If I understand correctly, given a big dataset of inputs you want to make a model which exactly fits all the inputs which are in the range [0, 5]? It might help getting an answer to know why your model requires 0 error, because unless that's absolutely necessary you should avoid that because your model won't generalize well.

Comment: What i'm doing is creating a function that describes a series of points so i don't have to store each of their values, so it does accept errors of up to 0.5 (absolute) so i can still guess the value of the points when drawing them. I'm looking at some spectral analysis papers to see if i can get something out of it.

Comment: I understand that you wish to represent your data with a function, but if I knew why, I could help you avoid future problems like overfitting (if you need to avoid that too). But anyways, with $n$ points, you can construct an $n - 1$ degree polynomial that is guaranteed to have $0$ error.

Comment: But there is a problem with interpolating large order polynomials: I would need to store n constants and that would defeat the purpose of the interpolation. I'm trying to solve the problem with fourier series.

Comment: I asked for a reason like that. Check this post out: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29198/using-fourier-analysis-to-fit-function-to-data